# Is it possible for credit card companies to check credit score in India?

Tags: credit-card, india, credit-score

I had two credit card applications rejected with the following reasons:

> - ...as your application is not in line with our existing credit
>     policy.
> - ...as it does not fulfill our internal policy criteria.

I might not be having a good credit rating as I do not have any existing loan or credit card. I'm a salaried employee with an annual salary of INR 1 Million (approx. $15,600). My salary account is not with either of the above two banks.

I have never applied for a [CIBIL](https://www.cibil.com/) score. Is it possible for the card issuing banks to check my score without my permission? Details which I have provided during the card applications only includes my PAN and Aadhar numbers.

Comment: Yes they can check your  `CIBIL` score. If you haven't checked you CIBIL score ever, check it and see if you have proablems in your score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Is it possible for the card issuing banks to check my score without my permission?**

As far as I understand these things, that is exactly the whole purpose of these sorts of credit-rating institutions.

The banks and other financial businesses are their customers. They exist to serve *those* customers. Their relationship, if any, with a consumer is probably secondary to that.

When you apply for credit, you give that business any permission needed.

Comment: My credit rating was NA. I have no credit history.

Answer (score 1):

Banks, NBFCs (Non-Banking Financial Companies), Telcos, and Insurance companies that are authorized by the RBI can access your CIBIL score. This can be done by using the PAN and Aadhar card details along with other personal details.

However, there are third parties who might try to access your credit reports for misguided intentions if they have access to your personal data. So, It's best to keep your PAN card and other personal details private.